# CSS are not linking with HTML in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am planned to insert the vertical scroll menu in the WordPress page.

Steps I have taken:

Step1: Created a folder and pasted all the css and javascript files into it.

Step2: In Wordpress, I have added a new page and in the html section I added the html codes and and properly linked the stylesheets and javascripts

EX:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are the paths of the files correct? Is network tab in developer tools giving any errors?

Comment: @Abhishek K R Have you tried using the full path to the files? Ex: `http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/css/reset.css` It's most likely a path issue. You can inspect the source of the page to see where it shows it is pulling from.

Comment: The paths are all wrong see my solution for the correct method.

Comment: @BarryMode  I had tried! that's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using the correct enqueuing principles in a child theme.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles');

function child_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'reset-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/reset.css', array());
}
```

This will add the reset.css style to every page in WordPress.

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: I already activated the child theme. If I add the function to the main theme will it work?

Comment: Custom functions should be added to the functions.php file in the child theme folder.

Comment: can you send an example code for enqueue and loading the css. Thanks

Comment: The example is in my answer above.

Comment: So let me confirm that is the only code for both enqueue and loading css

Comment: Enqueue and loading mean the same thing.  My example code will load a CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, you need to specify the links like this :--

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: why we need a php?

Comment: You are working with WordPress. Right ? Then you need to save your files as .php

Comment: @brk the `get_template_directory_uri()` will return the path to your current template. Assuming `css/reset.css` is located there, that's a solid answer.

Comment: Enqueue scripts and styles using the appropriate WordPress functions such as wp_enqueue_script()  and wp_enqueue_style() it will save you headaches in the future.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you should call `css` and `js` files into wp file system.
You should find the `functions.php` file that lies in `wp-content/themes/yourtheme`.

Take a look at the nex link
 https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```